# Weblogic10.3.5 install: Unrecognized option: -d64

Tags: java, jvm, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Im trying to set up weblogic in my machine.
I downloaded from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/wls-main-097127.html.

My PATH looks like this, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin;

Java - version in cmd prompt gives this,

C:\setups>java -version
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode)

Now, when i execute the weblogic jar file using the command as specified in the oracle documentation, C:\setups>java -d64 -jar wls1035_generic.jar , I get the below error.

Unrecognized option: -d64
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

How should i get rid and execute the jar file to install weblogic? pls help.

Comment: did you try running without the -d64 switch?

Comment: No. I can try now. I followed the documentation which uses -d64 flag. Thanks for your input. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue. It happened because I had a 32bit JDK and not the 64bit JDK that was required by the weblogic install package

- To check what version you have, you type the following in your terminal 
  java -d64 -version
  If you get an error then that is your issue, proceed as below:
- You can find the 64bit jdk at: [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)
- I think to avoid conflicts you might want to delete your current JDK